# Join 2 tables to retrieve name and count linq Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 tables `Orders` and `Items` and I am trying to query these 2 tables for statistics retrieval.

- `Orders` has columns `OrderID[PK]`, `ItemID[FK]`, `OrderStatus` etc.
- `Items` has columns `ItemID[PK]`, `ItemName`, `ItemPrice` etc.

I am fetching list of orders based on date range and then I am returning their counts based on their status.

Below is my `StatisticsResponse.cs` to return the response.

```
public class StatisticsResponse
{
    public int CancelledOrderCount { get; set; }
    public int CompletedOrderCount { get; set; }
    public int InProgressOrderCount { get; set; }
    public int TotalOrders { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,int> ItemOrders { get; set;}
}
```

This is how I am retrieving `Orders` between 2 dates.

```
var orders = _unitOfWork.OrderRepository
                        .GetMany(x => (x.OrderStatus == "Pending"
                                      && x.OrderDate.Value.Date >= dtStartDate 
                                      && x.OrderDate.Value.Date < dtEndDate) || 
                                      ((x.OrderStatus == "Completed" || x.OrderStatus == "Cancelled") 
                                        && x.DeliveryDate.Date >= dtStartDate || x.DeliveryDate.Date < dtEndDate) || (x.LastUpdated.Value.Date >= dtStartDate || x.LastUpdated.Value.Date < dtEndDate)).ToList();

if (orders != null)
{
    return new StatisticsResponse()
    {
          TotalOrders = orders.Count(),
          CancelledOrderCount = orders.Where(x => x.OrderStatus == "Cancelled").Count(),
          CompletedOrderCount = orders.Where(x => x.OrderStatus == "Completed").Count(),
          InProgressOrderCount = orders.Where(x => x.OrderStatus != "Completed" && x.OrderStatus != "Cancelled").Count()
    }
}
```

Now, in the `ItemOrders` property, which is of type `Dictionary<string,int>`, I want to group each item with their **name** and **count**. I have `ItemID` in my `orders` list, and I would like to join 2 tables to get the name before storing.

I have tried to use `GroupBy` as below but am totally stuck on how to get the name for the Item after grouping

```
ItemOrders = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    orders.GroupBy(x=>x.ItemID)// Stuck here
}
```

I also read about `GroupJoin` but couldn't quite make sure whether it can fit in here.

Could someone please let me know how I can join these 2 tables to get their name based on their `ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to achieve this with `GroupJoin` through various online example as below:

```
if (orders != null)
{
    var items = _unitOfWork.ItemRepository.GetAll();
    var itemOrders = items.GroupJoin(orders,
                                     item => item.ItemID,
                                     ord => ord.ItemID,
                                     (item, ordrs) => new
                                     {
                                         Orders = ordrs,
                                         itemName = item.ItemName
                                     });
            StatisticsResponse statsResponse = new StatisticsResponse()
            {
                 //...
            };
            foreach (var item in itemOrders)
            {
                statsResponse.ItemOrders.Add(item.itemName, item.Orders.Count());
            }
            return statsResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something along this:

```
using System.Entity.Data; //to use Include()
```

...

```
Dictionary<string,int> itemOrders = dbContext.Orders.Include(o=> o.Item)
                        .GroupBy(o=> o.Item)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.Name, g => g.Count());
```

This is assuming:

- There is a navigation property set up from Order to Item
- Each  Order has one Item

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. But since I had custom repository setup, I wasn't able to implement your answer. I have added my version of answer as Community Wiki below if it may help others one day..