# How to use Entity Framework with a database without relationships defined

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to EF so please bear with me. I am using Entity Framework with an existing database in which the relationships are not defined.

Using EF, I am able to produce the model, but obviously the 'navigational properties' are not working. Is there a way I can specify the mapping between the entities?

For example, in my `Product` entity, I have a field `CategoryID_fk` (maps to `Category` entity). But since the relationships are not defined, I cannot load a `Category` while loading a `Product` entity.

Can someone guide me in this regard?

I do understand that it would be preferable to refactor our database but I am unable to do that now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **FIX** the flawed database design! Seriously - any effort you put into "working around" this major flaw right now is **wasted time and effort** - instead, work on the **actual root cause** and fix that - **then** you'll see the benefits of your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

This link is very useful.http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/
I think field names are not suitable conventions.Try to change field name as CategoryId or Category_CategoryId .I think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do a group join. Basically you will retrieve `Products` and `Category` in separate queries and take an approach [as indicated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41654433/3615478).

Something along these lines:

```
var productCategoryList = products.GroupJoin
                            ( 
                                 categories,
                                 p=> p.productId,
                                 c=> c.CategoryId,
                                 (p, c) => new ProductCategory
                                 {
                                     //Create your Product Category model here
                                 }
                            ).AsEnumerable();
```